# NTAG215 AUTHLIM BRUTE FORCE LIMIT

Tags: nfc

I need to protect my NTAG215 from bad password after ten incorrect attempts.

First protected page 04 to 81:

**RAW COMMAND:** A2 83 04 00 00 04

After to enable brute force protection:

**RAW COMMAND:** A2 84 82 00 00 00

[image]
[image]

**HEX** 82 = **BIN** 10000010

- **PROT** = 1
- **CFGLCK** = 0
- **RFUI** = 0
- **NFC_CNT_EN** = 0
- **NFC_CNT_PWD_PROT** = 0
- **AUTHLIM** = 010 ( 10 attempts )

But after 3 incorrect attempts my NTAG215 seems dead.

NTAG213-216 data sheet:
https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/NTAG213_215_216.pdf

I'm doing something incorrectly?

Thanks for help.

**#SOLVED** ( Thanks to @**nanofarad** )
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

authlim is a three-bit number - 010 is not ten attempts, it's *binary* 10 attempts (meaning 2 attempts), so presumably on the third it locks itself.

You cannot set 10 attempts using AUTHLIM if AUTHLIM can only represent numbers from zero (binary 000) to seven (binary 111).

Comment: Thanks for the help, now i understand, i found this table to: https://www.binary-code.org/bits/3